# How can I improve the quality/graphics of my R plot for a Naive Bayes classifier visual

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, naivebayes

I tried a Naive Bayes classifier to see if I can predict if a person, given their age and estimated salary, would purchase a particular vehicle or not. The plot I got in the visualisation section looks not very smooth and clean, with white lines running across my plot. I'm assuiming the graphics/resolution is the problem but I am not sure.

This is a snippet of what the dataset looks like

```
Age EstimatedSalary Purchased
19         19000         0
35         20000         0
26         43000         0
27         57000         0
19         76000         0
27         58000         0
```

Here is the code

```
# Loading the data set

data <- read.csv(" *A csv sheet on people's age, salaries and whether or not they will purchase a certain vehicle* ")
data <- data[, 3:5]
attach(data)

# Encoding the dependent variable

data$Purchased <- factor(data$Purchased, levels = c(0, 1))
attach(data)

# Splitting the dataset

library(caTools)
set.seed(404)
split <- sample.split(Purchased, SplitRatio = 0.75)
train_set <- subset(data, split == T)
test_set <- subset(data, split == F)

# Feature scaling

train_set[-3] <- scale(train_set[-3])
test_set[-3] <- scale(test_set[-3])

# Training the model

library(e1071)
classifier <- naiveBayes(x = train_set[-3], y = train_set$Purchased)

# Predicting test results

y_pred <- predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-3])

# Construct the confusion matrix

(cm <- table(test_set[, 3], y_pred))
```

Below is the code that I used to visualise the results

```
# Visualising the results

library(ElemStatLearn)
set <- test_set
x1 <- seq(min(set[, 1]) - 1, max(set[, 1]) + 1, by = 0.01)
x2 <- seq(min(set[, 2]) - 1, max(set[, 2]) + 1, by = 0.01)
grid_set <- expand.grid(x1, x2)
colnames(grid_set) <- c("Age", "EstimatedSalary")
y_grid <- predict(classifier, newdata = grid_set)
plot(set[, -3], main = "Naive Bayes: Test set", xlab = "Age", ylab = "EstimatedSalary", xlim = range(x1), ylim = range(x2))
contour(x1, x2, matrix(as.numeric(y_grid), length(x1), length(x2)), add = T)
points(grid_set, pch = ".", col = ifelse(y_grid == 1, "Springgreen3", "tomato"))
points(set, pch = 21, bg = ifelse(set[, 3] == 1, "green4", "red3"))
```

[Naive Bayes classifier plot on the test set predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUAfB.png)

Would like to know the reason for the white lines running up and down the plot and why it does not look smooth?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was giving me the weird lines and the low quality resolution. Adding the "cex = n" parameter to the "points()" function in the graph with n = 5 solved this.

[image]

Revised block of code

```
set <- test_set
x1 <- seq(min(set[, 1]) - 1, max(set[, 1]) + 1, by = 0.01)
x2 <- seq(min(set[, 2]) - 1, max(set[, 2]) + 1, by = 0.01)
grid_set <- expand.grid(x1, x2)
colnames(grid_set) <- c("Age", "EstimatedSalary")
y_grid <- predict(classifier, newdata = grid_set)
plot(set[, -3], main = "Naive Bayes: Test set", xlab = "Age", ylab = "EstimatedSalary", xlim = range(x1), ylim = range(x2))
contour(x1, x2, matrix(as.numeric(y_grid), length(x1), length(x2)), add = T)
points(grid_set, pch = ".", col = ifelse(y_grid == 1, "Springgreen3", "tomato"), cex = 5)
points(set, pch = 21, bg = ifelse(set[, 3] == 1, "green4", "red3"))
```

The revised line of code in the above block

```
points(grid_set, pch = ".", col = ifelse(y_grid == 1, "Springgreen3", "tomato"), cex = 5)
```

However the case, I would still like to know the reason behind how this happened because the explanation available in R about the functions and the parameters were not that clear to me.

Would appreciate any help given!